# Does Pardoning mean something different in Pylea?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer, angel

In Season 2 Episode 21 *"Through the Looking Glass"*, at the end of this exchange

> **Silas**: And if we tell you 'silent' you shut your cow mouth! 
>   **Cordy**: Pardon me? 
>   **Silas**: Pardon - your majesty?  Don't you feel you have done enough - pardoning......for one day?

Silas lifts the lid off the platter he brought froth revealing

> Lorne's severed head

now looking at things currently it seems Pylea is sorta "backwards" to Earth where:

- humans are considered animals (cows) and the culture of the world is to enslave them
- Lorne's singing burns people (as indicated by his mum saying *"It's Burns"* when helping Angel escape by singing)
- Angel, having become some sort of Pylean Vampire equivalent, doesn't burn in the sun(s) and has a reflection

so, I am wondering, since to pardon is

> the action of forgiving or being forgiven for an error or offence.

and in Pylea it seems even everything that is a crime comes with an execution, does pardoning someone mean something different in Pylea and it's all been apart of Cordy's misunderstanding (like how what she imagined the Groosalug to be); or was Silas's reveal to show that him and the other priests don't actually obey Cordy at all?

Comment: In the U.S., a "pardon" is usually used to get someone off death row.  In Pylea's backward world, a "pardon" therefore means to have someone executed.

Comment: Numfar! Perform the Dance of Pardoning!

Answer (score 5):

There's no indication that they misunderstood what Cordy had said, or that the concept of pardoning someone was different in Pylea than on Earth.  They beheaded Lorne because they wanted to, and despite Cordy's pardon, not because of it.

You already quoted the most relevant line:

> **Silas:** And if we tell you 'silent' you shut your cow mouth!

Doesn't really sound like someone who is going to follow her orders, does it?